# How to view a jpg file which was recovered after being deleted and it's attribute was checked to hidden before deletion?

Tags: windows-10, permissions, photos, file-recovery

I had a photo which I turned to hidden because it was a personal photo which I didn't want others to see. I then deleted it permanently in haste but I needed it again.

I then downloaded Recuva after reading about it on Microsoft's forum and recovered the photo after specifying the path of the folder in which it was originally stored.

Now, I am unable to view the photo and it shows the message - "It looks like you don't have permission to view this file. Check permissions and try again."

I searched how to do it on Microsoft's forum.
This is it's link -> https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/it-looks-like-you-dont-have-permission-to-view/a6ba4639-319d-474c-925f-f2a8a55113ea

I followed through Method 3 until Step 5 but the option with the checkbox mentioned in Step 6 doesn't appear and I still can't view the photo.

Any help on how to solve this issue would be great.

Update: Now it shows "It looks like we don't support this file format" after trying to change it's ownership.

Comment: TBH it makes very little sense but I'd just recover the photo to a FAT32/exFAT formatted USB stick. I don't know what the photo was deleted from, but did Recuva show a preview of the photo?

Comment: @Joep van Steen The photo was stored in a folder in Desktop in This PC in E Drive. Recuva didn't show a preview of it.

Comment: @User, what is the size of the file? Have you check the content with kind of hex viewer?

Comment: @Romeo Ninov The size of the file is 26.7 KB and it's size on disk is 28.0 KB. I don't know about hex viewer and how to use it.

Comment: Seems like a very small file, are you sure it was recovered? You may [take ownership](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-take-ownership-of-a-folder-in-windows-10/) of the file.

Comment: If it was deleted from SSD. NTFS formatted it was 99.9% likely trimmed.

Comment: Update: Now it shows "It looks like we don't support this file format" after trying to change it's ownership.

Comment: The file has not been recovered successfully.

Comment: Exactly, open in HxD and see if it contains data at all.

Comment: I installed HxD. Then I recovered the file in an external FAT32 pen drive and opened it in HxD. It's just showing zeroes. And Recuva didn't show a preview of the file too. And the same message of file format not being supported is being displayed.

Comment: If just zeros it was probable recovered from a SSD or SMR hard drive. The data was trimmed.